# Unity 3D failed to load plugin 'opencv_world460.dll' because one or more of its dependencies could not be loaded

Tags: c#, c++, .net, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load and use the opencv library in Unity via a custom plugin dll and opencv_world460.dll (which I also compiled myself from source). The plugin works fine and I am able to pass data to and from Unity managed memory and the unmanaged C++ .dll plugin. The plugin itself is also able to reference, call, and link against my opencv headers and compiled libraries. However, when attempting to load opencv_world460.dll Unity throws an error stating:

"Plugins: Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/opencv_world460.dll' because one or more of its dependencies could not be loaded."

To find the source of my problem I ran the dependency tracing tool "Dependency" on opencv_world460.dll. As far as I can tell, the tool is able to resolve all of the dependencies required the run this dll on my machine. Obviously Unity is still unable to find or load one of them for whatever reason. The attached image is the dependency list for opencv_world460.dll. The dependency tool I was using doesn't appear to supply any easy way of copying the text, so I had to use the image.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to track down specifically *which* dependency is failing to load? My best guess is there's a problem with all of the api-ms-win-crt dll's being forwarded to ucrtbase.dll. In the meantime, to test this theory, I'm going to go download the redistributable containing those actual dlls and install it to see if that has any impact on the problem.

Comment: You can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what files unity tries to load but not found.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the trace.

Comment: it's likely **not** the CRT stuff. -- this is a hard-to-track error. dependency walking is fuzzy (not all LoadLibrary calls indicate a required dependency, some are just exploratory). if I had to guess, opencv_world still needs the separate opencv_ffmpeg_whatever dll. -- if you've downloaded opencv, it should come with all the required DLLS, and you **"just"** need to get them on `PATH` (add directory to path, or move them to path)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am also bringing in opencc_ffmpeg, and that dll actually loads just fine.

Comment: Ok, I finally got it to work, but this isn't much of a solution. I had been working on my Windows 11 laptop. When I tried the original procedure of getting OpenCV in Unity3D on my Windows 10 desktop, it worked just fine.